# Electromechanical coupling

Tags: electromagnetism, polarization

[Electrostriction](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp971522c) is an electromechanical coupling phenomenon observed in all insulators. It relates the polarization to strain by:

$x_{ij} = Q_{ijkl} P_k P_l$

where $x$ is the electrostrictive strain, $Q$ is the electrostrictive coefficient, and $P$ is the induced polarization.

My confusion is:

If electrostrictive strain is equal to elecrostriction coefficient times the square of polarization, then if we divide the strain by the square of polarization, we obtain higher electrostriction coefficient for lower polarization since polarization is in the denominator, but then if the polarization increases it means that the material has a very good response to electric field and also when it has a very good response to electric field it will also deform more, so higher polarization means higher strain and higher strain means higher electrostrictive coefficient because strain is in the numerator

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is based on a mistake, as far as I can see: If you divide by $P^2$ you get
$$\frac{x_{ij}}{P^2} = Q_{ijkl} \widehat{P}_k \widehat{P}_l$$
where I'm using the hat to denote unit vectors in the given direction. Thus for a constant-value tensor, for example, the expression is independent of the absolute value of $P$ and only depends on its direction. (And don't think that on the left-hand side of the equation you can change $P^2$ while the strain remains constant: The strain is determined by the value of $P$!)

That being said, in principle such a material law would be allowed to have a tensor that depends on $P$. The exact form of such a non-linear material law would depend on the system, and probably needs more concrete consideration than yours or experimentation to determine the exact dependence on $P$.